# How to access storyboard items without @IBOutlets?

Tags: swift

I am currently working in a IOS app where I have created a storyboard and some `viewControllers`.

Because many of the areas are similar I choose to create a generic `viewController` and then populate it with a controller that extends `UIViewController`.

Since I cannot add two different classes to a `viewController` in interface builder, I cannot link the `viewController` to two different controllers.

What would be the best way to accomplish such task?

Having a  controller linked with the storyboard `viewController`  and this controller handles every view that needs to be instantiated?

Comment: Does all the controllers have the same UI? Why do you want to use a single controller and make the code complicated?

Comment: All the controllers will instantiate a base view that will be equal for many. 
The parts that are different I can create them with UIKit to help me out.  But the parts that stay the same are crated with interface builder for simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use tags in Interface Builder for your controls.

For instance, let say you set a label with a tag of 100, and a button with a tag of 110.

```
var label : UILabel! { view.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel }
var button : UIButton! { view.viewWithTag(110) as? UIButton }
```

So now, you can do things like:

```
label.text = "Yeppee!"
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Exactly what I needed. In terms of scalability, is it more reasonable to have multiple controllers and views or a controller that handles everything plus the views?

Comment: It really depends on you needs. But having distributed code is always better than all centralized in one place, if you have the choice. So do not hesitate to have multiple controllers, each responding to a specific set of responsibilities instead of having a huge one centralizing everything.